# About the number of normalizers of Sylow p-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

A [textbook](https://www.routledge.com/Groups-and-Characters/Hill/p/book/9781584880387) I'm reading claims:

> if $G$ is a finite group and if $p$ is prime diving $|G|$, then the normalizers of the Sylow p-subgroups of $G$ have order $|G|/s_p$ (where $s_p$ is the number of Sylow p-subgroups) and there are exactly $s_p$ such normalizers

This quite clear to me. What is not clear is in a previous paragraph he's claiming also:

> "The result is that A5 has at least six subgroups of order 10. If there were any other subgroups of order 10, Thm 7.1 (i.e. 1st Sylow Thm) would apply to them because a subgroup is a group in itw own right and these additional subgroups would likewise have Sylow subgroups of order 5. But there are only six subgroups of order 5 in all of A5 and there can be only six subgroups of order 10"

How this can be correct, since it applies the 1st Sylow thm to a 10-subgroups, where 10 is not a prime?

Let's take an example: $A_5$. This group has $6$ 5-sylow which are cyclic. Considering the conjugation acting on a 5-sylow, we know the orbit of a given 5-sylow is $6$, since all p-sylow are conjugates.
So we can use the orbit-stabilizer thm to derive the normalizer (as a 5-sylow stabilizer under conjugation) size of each 5-sylow, i.e. $$60 / 6 = 10$$.
Since each of the 6 5-sylow has its own distinct normalizer, we could claim there **at least $6$ subgroups of order $10$**.

What is not clear to me is why we can be sure there are no more subgroups of order $10$ than  those ones.

I mean: why there cannot be other order 10 subgroups which are **not** normalizer of a p-subgroup?

I hope my explanation is clear, sorry in case.

Comment: Where in the quoted statement does it say that "there are no other subgroups of the same order"?

Comment: It's in the previous paragraph: "The result is that $A_5$ has at least six subgroups of order 10. If there were any other subgroups of order 10, Thm 7.1 (i.e. 1st Sylow Thm) would apply to them because a subgroup is a group in itw own right and these additional subgroups would likewise have Sylow subgroups of order 5. But there are only six subgroups of order 5 in all of $A_5$ and there can be only six subgroups of order 10"

Comment: Then perhaps you should include that part, too?

Comment: The first doubt is how it can apply the 1st Sylow thm to subgroups of order 10, since 10 is not a prime.

Comment: You are applying Sylow's 1st Theorem to a group of order 10 to extract its Sylow 5-subgroups, which are also Sylow 5-subgroups of the original group. You are not obtaining subgroups of order 10. It is also unclear to me if this is an assertion about $A_5$ in particular, or a general claim that "in a group $G$, if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $N$ is the normalizer of $P$, then the only subgroups of order $|N|$ are normalizers of Sylow $p$-subgroups". Is that claim made explicitly somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @ArturoMagidin this made my concern clear.

Comment: The example Is using $A_5$, the only claim Is the First One I quoted. So the "general claim you are mentioning would be wrong in general? Since this exactly my 2nd concern in the question.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out exactly what the book is saying...

Comment: Pag 72/73. However this happens since the order of the normalizer of 5-sylow Is 10, which still contain 5 as factor. So this cannot be made generic. It depends exactly on $|G|/s_p$ when factored, I guess

Comment: Nonsense. Since the normalizer of a $p$-Sylow subgroup always contains the $p$-Sylow subgroup, and the $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal in its own normalizer, each normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ contains exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup of itself, which is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Nonsense about what exactly? Is that working for $A_5$ only? Since for $A_5$ his claim Is correct. There can be other subgroups of order |N|?

Comment: Nonsense that "it depends exactly on $|G|/s_p$ when factored". The order of the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup is always a multiple of the order of the Sylow $p$-subgroup, so the fact that $5$ is a factor of $10$ is not the reason "this happens". In any finite group, each Sylow $p$-subgroup is contained in exactly one normalizer subgroup, and each normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup contains exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. "exactly on $|G|/s_p$ when factored" is irrelevant.

Comment: OK but you didn't answer to my question. There can be other subgroups of the order of |N|?

Comment: Probably I got it: since all p-subgroups exhaust the subgroup of order p, and since each p-subgroup is in one to one correspondence with its normalizer, also all p-normalizers are exhausting the possible subgroups of order $|N$|. Is that what you meant? Even if I would not be fully conviced by that.

Comment: As Derek Holt has [shown elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4513069/742), this is not a valid statement in general (I didn't have a counterexample, but couldn't prove it either). The reason it works in $A_5$ is that subgroups of order $10$ can only have one subgroup of order $5$. In general, if $H$ has the same order as $|N|$, and $P$ is a $p$-Sylow contained in $H$, then $N_H(P)=N_G(P)\cap H$; if $P$ is normal in $H$, then $N_G(P)\cap H=H$, so $H\subseteq N_G(P)$, and you get equality. But if $H$ contains more than one Sylow subgroup, then you run into problems.

Comment: tx @ArturoMagidin please raise this comment as answer so I can vote for it. I was still working onto it, tx for confirming it's not a general case. Derek Holt used in yet another post of mine the SmallGroup(324, 160). The 2-sylow normalisers are isomorphic to $A_4$ in that case, but there's a subgroup class of order $12$ which have not any 2-sylow normal in them. In $A_4$ the normal 2-sylow are isomorphic to $V_4$, so I tried to find a similar group with $V_4$ as 2-sylow and order $12$ without those 2-sylow normal in them,  the candidates could be $D_{12}$. I'm trying to confirm this by SAGE.

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate of your other query, since your query is answered there: it is not true in general that a subgroup of the same order as the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup is necessarily a normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup.